# Initialization of object in Java

Tags: java, oop, constructor, new-operator, final

I am learning some basic OOP concepts in Java. Consider the following code snippet:

```
class my_class{
    int a;
    public my_class() {
    System.out.print(a+" ");
    a = 10;
    System.out.print(a);
    }
}
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    my_class my_object = new my_class();
    }
}
```

The output of the following code is: **0 10**

According to my understanding:

1. `my_class` is the name of the class
2. `my_object` is the reference of the object I am creating
3. `new` operator allocates memory and returns it's address which is stored in `my_object`
4. `my_class()` is the constructor which initializes the object's fields with default value 0 and later assigns it 10

Now consider the code:

```
class my_class{
    final int a;
    public my_class() {
    a=10;
    System.out.print(a);
    }
}
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    my_class my_object = new my_class();
    }
}
```

From my previous understanding it should have created `my_object` with field `final int a` set to the default value 0 which should be unchangeable and flag an error at `a=10;` but instead it works and prints the output: **10**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Because you are allowed to initialize `final` variables inside the constructor. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Why do you think that it should be `0`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think so because of the previous code. I am assuming everytime an object is created, it's fields are initialized with default values(0/0.0/null) and then we can assign it a new value via constructor if we want to.

Comment: A `final` field that hasn't been explicitly initialized may have a default value of 0/null, but will always have to be explicitly initialized in the constructor before it can be used. There are some edge-cases where you can 'see' the default value of a `final` field, but for normal usages, a `final` field should be considered to have no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize any `final` field once, *either* in the constructor (that is, each constructor once), or in its declaration.

(Notably, if you want the arguments to the constructor to play a part in the value of the final variable, you must initialize it in the constructor -- otherwise final variables would be kind of useless!)

Comment: Can't a final variable be also initailized along with it's declaration?

Comment: @MayankMittal Yes, but then you cannot assign it anymore in the constructor.